# Selenium C# dropdown jumps back to original state

Tags: c#, selenium, drop-down-menu, dropdownbox

Currently I am working on a little project to verify some login accounts.
I run into this problem that when i select the provider Canal Digitaal and then click 'Login', the dropdown box jumps back to it's initial state. When doing manually its working fine but when automating with a UnitTest it doesn't. I simplified the code (without POM) and its still not working. Hopefully someone knows what my problem is. For a similar site its working fine but for this it aint.. This is my code now:

```
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://video.sport1.nl");

        driver.FindElement(By.Id("login")).Click();

        new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("provider"))).SelectByValue("canaldigitaal");

        driver.FindElement(By.Id("login")).Click();
```

Comment: Are you sure that `"canaldigitaal"` is correct value?

Comment: Yes i am sure. it gets selected as well. but as soon as i perform the click on the login button it will jump back to Sport1 Go.                         <select id="provider" class="inputbox-shop" style="width: 265px;" name="provider">
<option selected="" value="sport1go">Sport1 Go</option>
<option value="canaldigitaal">Canal Digitaal</option>

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there are two elements on the page with ID = login. You can see that by using `driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#login")).Count` and it returns 2. One is the DIRECT INLOGGEN link (top right) and the other is Inloggen (red button). You are mistakenly clicking the DIRECT INLOGGEN link which resets everything. Try this

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://video.sport1.nl");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("login")).Click();
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("provider"))).SelectByValue("canaldigitaal");
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.login > #login")).Click();
```

I grabbed a parent DIV first `div.login` (DIV with class login) then found the `A` child (>) with ID login.

Comment: Thanks! This appeared to be the issue. I tried both Xpath and ID's and both didn't work. Now i see that the Xpath i used (a//*[@id='login']) is matching with the two buttons. I thought ID's were unique.. :(

Comment: HTML IDs are *supposed* to be unique on the page by HTML standards but that's up to the devs to adhere to that standard. I've learned the hard way at times that doesn't always happen. I'm glad you found the issue. If this answered your question, please accept it as the answer.